# What's the correct version of this 'converse' of De Finetti's theorem? ("conditional" IID => exchangeable)

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

From what I've read, there is a statement that is roughly like:

"*If a sequence of random variables is IID conditional on some other random variables, then it is [exchangeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables#Definition)*",

but I can't find a rigorous trustworthy source from which to just cite this result or whatever the correct version of it is (it isn't even 100% clear what it means in the first place - there is more than one possible interpretation).

The interpretation that I currently think is most likely to be the correct one is the following... **Is the following statement true?**

Let $(X_j)_{j=1}^{\infty} : (\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbf{P}) \to (\mathbf{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbf{R}))$ be a sequence of random variables. If there is another random variable $Y$ such that for every $N \geq 1$ we have: $$ \mathbf{E}\bigl[ X_1\cdots X_N | \sigma(Y)\bigr] =  \mathbf{E}\bigl[X_1 | \sigma(Y)\bigr]^N, $$ then the sequence $(X_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is exchangeable.

Comment: See pp. 187 http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Math%20Complete/Probability%20and%20statistics/Foundations%20of%20Modern%20Probability%20-%20Olav%20Kallenberg.pdf